# Find all the numbers $x$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(2n)!}=0$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Find all the numbers $x$ such that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(2n)!}=0$$

Is it by some tricks on Taylor series on $\sin{x}$, $e^x$?

Comment: sorry, i've edited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $x=z^2$, then this sum is $\frac{1}{2} \left(e^z+e^{-z}\right)$. So you need to find all $z$ such that $e^z=-e^{-z}$.

This is the complex number answer, where $z$ and $x$ can be complex.

You can restrict $x$ to real values by first doing the above for $x\geq 0$ and showing that there is no such $z$ and then, when $x<0$, solving $x=-z^2$ and noting the the resulting power series is $\cos z$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

As

$$e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{x^r}{r!},$$

$$\implies e^{-x}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^rx^r}{r!}$$

$$\implies \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2r}}{(2r)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=y^2$ for some complex no. $y$.

Then we have $\frac{1}{2}(e^{y}+e^{-y})=0$

$e^y=-e^{-y}\Rightarrow e^{2y}=-1$